# Zend Framework Table insert MySQL Expression

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Just wanted to ask if there is an easyer way to do this (to use the FROM_UNIXTIME expression):

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();
$db = $table->getAdapter();

$table->insert(array(
    'date'=>new Zend_Db_Expr($db->quoteInto('FROM_UNIXTIME(?)', time())),
    'name'=>$name,
    'password'=>'',
    'passworddate'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
));
```

I mean it's a lot overhead just to use FROM_UNIXTIME. And it's looks not very clean in my opptinion.

Comment: why not store time-stamp as it is . Where date column is of type int(11) ?

Comment: Because i want to have the posibility to use mysql time functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use MySQL's `NOW()` function unless there's a time difference between your 
application and database servers.

```
'date' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
```

If the application server time takes priority, why not simply try

```
'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
```

Comment: "unless there's a time difference between your application" Yes that's why i use the PHP function instead. I want all my time things done by php to avoid problems with a different database time / timezones.

Comment: Yes, good idea for the current problem but i'm still thinking about this unneccesary complex solution i had which seems to be the only way to insert mysql expressions with a parameter. And another question i'm asking mysqlf at the moment is, if i getting the same time when i user UNIX_TIMESTAMP later to retrive it (when the mysql server is in a different timezone).

Comment: @Johni I think the example in your question is probably the best way to go about using expressions with parameters. As for timezones, all PHP's date/time methods use the configured or server timezone. For example, if I run `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` right now, I get `2011-08-30 12:13:08` whereas somebody in another part of the world will get something wildly different.

Comment: Yes, thats my point. With date('Y-m-d H:i:s') in my database is a complete different time depending on the timezone difference to mysql. So i cant mix it with UNIX_TIMESTAMP to convert it back.

Comment: @Johni Ah, excellent point. You might want to store the timezone along with the date in that case. Have a read of this - http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html

Comment: @Johni: Why not work with UTC time, using MySQL's `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` for instance?
Or is the DB servers clock accuracy unreliable (meaning: of by a few minutes or so)?
If the clocks *are* reliable, then the differing timezones won't matter, because UTC time will always be the same. From there on it's easy to calculate local time within either PHP or MySQL. As a minor added benefit: no need to add in PHP `time()` anymore.